# Finding tighter upper bound of a complicated function

Tags: polynomials, inequalities, asymptotics

Define the following functions from $[0,1) \to \mathbb{R}$:

Let $f(x)=1-x^n$.

Let $r=1-\frac{1}{n(1-x)+1}$ and $u(x)=\sum_{i=1}^n\binom{n}{i}\frac{x^{n-i}(1-x)^i(1-r^i)}{(1-x^n)(1-r)i}$.

Let $g(x)=1-\left(1-\frac{\left(1-x^{n}\right)+\left(1-x^n-nx^{n-1}(1-x)\right)(1-u(x))}{n}\right)^{n}$.

What is the maximum value of $h(x)=\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ on the interval $[0,1]$, across all integers $n\geq1$?

This question came up in our research. By testing values of $n$ up to $1000$, we found that the maximum value seemed to asymptotically approach something close to $1.41$. Unfortunately, $h(x)$ is not monotonically decreasing for $n$, so we cannot bound it by its maximum for smaller values of $n$.

We already know that $h(x)\leq\frac{1}{1-1/e}\approx 1.582$. This is because $g(x)\geq 1-(1-\frac{1-x^n}{n})^n\geq 1- e^{-(1-x^n)}\geq 1-e^{-1}$ and $f(x)\leq 1$. However, we hope to achieve a much tighter bound, closer to $1.41$.

Empirically, for all values of $n$, $h(x)$ seems to increase from $x=0$, until reaching a peak close to $x=1$. The peak moves closer to $1$ for larger $n$. The function then drops off quickly to approach $h(x)=1$ near $x=1$.

Comment: Why can't you just find a hard lower bound on $n$ beyond which the maximum is close to $1.4$, and then use a program to exhaustively check the remaining cases?

Comment: The maximum value of h(x) seems to asymptotically approach 1.41 , getting larger for larger n. We need to prove that it is less than 1.41 for all n, so we can't exhaustively prove the bound.

Comment: I don't think you read my comment. For example, prove that for every $n > 1000$ the maximum is less than $1.42$, and then use a computer to check all smaller $n$.

Comment: Ah, my apologies - I misunderstood. I'm not sure how you could prove that for every $n>1000$, the maximum is less than $1.42$. You're right that this becomes the crux of the problem. Did you have a particular technique in mind to show that $h(x)<1.42$?

Comment: I didn't actually try, because honestly your functions look scarily complicated, but the generic idea is to use asymptotic analysis to find the asymptotic behaviour, and then to extract hard bounds from that analysis to get a lower bound on when it stays within a certain fixed threshold from the asymptotic bound. Of course, the smaller the threshold, the bigger the lower bound (and so the more computation you need to settle the smaller cases).